# how to plot 8x8 correlation matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to plot an `8x8 correlation matrix` between the different feature scores and the corresponding chances of admit. May I know how I am supposed to do so?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pandas as pd

admit_data = np.genfromtxt('admission_predict.csv', delimiter= ',')
X_data, Y_data = admit_data[1:,1:8], admit_data[1:,-1]
x_train, x_test, y_train_, y_test_ = train_test_split(
                                            X_data, 
                                            Y_data, 
                                            test_size=0.3, 
                                            random_state=42
                                      )
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = scaler.fit_transform(x_test)
y_train = y_train_.reshape(len(y_train_), no_labels)
y_test = y_test_.reshape(len(y_test_), no_labels)

data = admit_data
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Serial No.','GRE Score','TOEFL Score','University Rating','SOP','LOR','CGPA','Research','Chance of Admit'])
df.corr()
```

This is the code I'm reading now and my file looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB9Zk.png)

Please help me plot a `8x8 correlation matrix` as of now my code doesn't return a `8x8 correlation matrix`

Comment: So, does the dataframe contain the relevant data? If so, isn't most of your code irrelevant to the problem?

Comment: Also, unrelated to the question, but you are far better off reading the csv file with `pd.read_csv(filename)`. Then you don't have to specify the column names again.

Comment: @Felix hi thanks for the comments as the rest of the code is for other part of the questions where i need to split the data sets.

Comment: But it doesn't relate to the question you are asking. I understand it might be important to you, but to other people reading this question it can be confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cors = df.corr()
plt.matshow(cors)
plt.yticks(range(cors.shape[1]), cors.columns, fontsize=7)
plt.xticks(range(cors.shape[1]), cors.columns, fontsize=7, rotation=90)
plt.colorbar()
```

to use all except "Serial No" column use this cors instead:

```
cors = df.drop("Serial No.", axis=1).corr()
```

Comment: hi for your code its printing 9x9 (as my csv file got 9 columns) but im trying to get 8x8(excluding serial no) may i know if there is a way to exclude that column?

Comment: added the example, use df.drop("Serial No.", axis=1).corr()